# Conexão do SQL SERVER 2014 com o NET BEANS

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

sou novo aqui e essa é a minha primeira pergunta rs...

Então, eu não consigo de jeito nenhum fazer a conexão do SQL SERVER com o NET BEANS.... Eu coloquei o JDBC já na pasta da biblioteca, segui vários tipos de tutorias no youtube e ainda não consegui. Os erros que estão dando agora se quer consigo entende-los.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter  at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
>     at projetoteste.Conector.connect(Conector.java:28)  at
>   projetoteste.Main.main(Main.java:27) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 15 more
>   C:\Users\guga_\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projetoTeste\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1328:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\guga_\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projetoTeste\nbproject\build-impl.xml:948:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

As minhas classes estão assim:

```
package projetoteste;
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author guga_
 */
public class Conector 
{
       public static Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException{  

    Connection con =null;  

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    String connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=guBanco;user=Honorato;password=1234";  

    try{

    con=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    System.out.println("Connection is successfull");

    }

    catch(SQLException e){

     System.out.println(e);

    }
        return con;
    }
}
```

E a classe main está dessa forma:

```
package projetoteste;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import static projetoteste.Conector.connect;
/**
 *
 * @author guga_
 */
public class Main 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        // TODO code application logic here

        connect();  


    }
}
```

Procurei muito antes de fazer essa pergunta aqui, então perdão se soar boba... Obrigado pela atenção e por quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Qual a versão do jdk que está utilizando ?

Comment: eu estou usando a versão 11.0.2

Comment: Bom dependendo da versão do driver JDBC não tem compatibilidade com java 11. neste [link](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=57782) você encontra a versão mais atual do **mssql_jdbc** ou você pode clicar com botão direito no projeto -> propriedades -> categorias: executar -> Opções VM: adicionar esse argumento: **--add-modules java.xml.bind** . Essa última opção não funciona caso seu projeto precise rodar no java 8 !